# joomla upgrade has changed my article links v.3.2.7 - v.3.4.8

Tags: upgrade, joomla3.0

I have recently update my joomla site to v.3.4.8. My article links used to be : component/content/article.html?id=xxx. Now they are component/content/?xxx&itemid=yyy.

What could have happened on the upgrade?

Comment: http://joomla.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the upgrade has blown away something on the SEF (Search Engine Friendly) URLs configuration...

Follow this guide and review your config https://docs.joomla.org/Enabling_Search_Engine_Friendly_(SEF)_URLs

Comment: Doesn't look like OP had SEF URLs enabled to begin with.